# Criar array associativo com outros arrays em PHP para usar como retorno JSON

Tags: php, json

Como exemplo, vou usar o que me foi passado de forma bem simples, esse `Array` será obtido com dados vindos de uma consulta de um `BD`:

```
$S1 = [[0,100], [1,200], [2,700]];
$S2 = [[0,700], [1,300], [2,400]];
$Label = [[0,SPI], [1,MVA], [2,ITB]];
```

Preciso criar um `Array` único com essas informações para conseguir um retorno `JSON` válido, mas não entendo como fazer e não estou conseguindo associar os `Arrays` e as tentativas que fiz ficaram estranhas, o final não ficou correto.

Comment: Tem certeza que está correto essas informações? Não me parece correto essa declaração desses arrays (posso estar enganado, faz um tempo q não uso php).

Imagino que seria algo assim:
$S1 = [[0,100], [1,200], [2,700]]; ???

Comment: Estou tendo erro de sintaxe na suas declarações de array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que esta seja sua resposta:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $S1 = [[0,100], [1,200], [2,700]];
    $S2 = [[0,700], [1,300], [2,400]];
    $Label = [[0,'SPI'], [1,'MVA'], [2,'ITB']];

    $retorno = array('S1' => $S1, 'S2' => $S2, 'Label' => $Label);
    echo json_encode($retorno);
?>
```

Comment: Olá @Christian Luã Lemos, valeu pela excelente dica, só me diz uma coisa, existe dentro do PDO a possibilidade ou recurso da linguagem para que a minha consulta já venha formatada como no exemplo que citei.
$S1 = [[0,100], [1,200], [2,700]];
$S2 = [[0,700], [1,300], [2,400]];
$Label = [[0,'SPI'], [1,'MVA'], [2,'ITB']];

Comment: De acordo com a documentação, talvez o FETCH_ASSOC. Em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que estejam erradas as declarações desses arrays.. então vou considerar que o correto seria dessa forma:

```
$S1 = [[0,100], [1,200], [2,700]];
$S2 = [[0,700], [1,300], [2,400]];
$Label = [[0,'SPI'], [1,'MVA'], [2,'ITB']];

$arr = [
        'S1' => $S1,
        'S2' => $S2,
        'Label' => $Label
    ];

var_dump(json_encode($arr));
```